# How to I return information from a widgets function to another page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on a project with a team where I implemented a barcode scanner that is going to be a widget on a "search" page. The issue I am currently facing is that I use the barcode to generate a list of ingredients that I want to include in the search but I don't know how to return that information to the search page. I have tried two methods so far:

1. I tried creating a member variable of the scanner class that I would then access on the search page when I need it but because my function that returns the list is a part of the private state class that I am unsure how to access from the public class. This is the method I would prefer to solve.
2. I have tried using the Navigator class to push and pop the information from the seperate screens but the issue is the barcode scanner is automatically closed once a barcode is scanned so I can't pop from the stack or else it will leave the search page and go back to whatever page was previous.

Here is the code I have. The first is the function that opens the barcode scanner, scans a barcode and creates an ingredient list that I return. This 'test' list is what I'd ideally like to set as a class member for the public portion of the class not the private state class.

```
Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal(BuildContext context) async {
String barcodeScanRes;
List<String> test;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
      "#ff6666", "Cancel", true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
} on PlatformException {
  barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
}

// If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
// message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
// setState to update our non-existent appearance.
if (!mounted) return null;

//Call the backend with the barcode to return the Bread Crumb list
List<String> breadCrumbs = await BackendRequest.barcode("089836187635", "42e96d88b6684215c9e260273b5e56b0522de18e");

//If the backend does not return us anything this displays a popup
if(breadCrumbs == null){
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomDialog(
       title: "Uh Oh",
       description:
        "Barcode not found in our database, please try entering the item manually",
       buttonText: "Okay",
      ),
    );
}
else{
  setState(() {
   _scanBarcode = breadCrumbs.toString();
  });

 //Check the breadcrumbs for usable ingredients
 test = await getIngredients(breadCrumbs, "42e96d88b6684215c9e260273b5e56b0522de18e");
}

setState(() {
   _itemName = test[0].toString();
  });

//Navigator.pop(context, test);
```

}

Here is where I add my widget to the search page. All I do is add the widget and the build function within my scanner class handles onPressed() functionality.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Input an Ingredient",
                hintText: "Search",
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                suffixIcon: ScanButton(),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use provide consumer pattern in which you can put all this page into one parent theme child and than you can access variable and all other stuff.

> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

other wise you can also use block patten

> https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1

or if you dont want to use that in that case you can make one common class and declare one static varible in that and set varible on result after scaning in completed and use when ever you want